# Flex in full screen mode?

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to flex. I've developed a sample page with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application height="100%" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" backgroundGradientColors="[#5b4ffb, #5594fb]" themeColor="#808080" cornerRadius="3" width="100%">
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.events.CloseEvent;
private function clickHandler(event:Event):void {
  if (UserID.text=="")
  {
      Alert.show("Please Enter your user name","Message");
      return;
  }
  if (Pwd.text=="")
  {
      Alert.show("Please Enter your Password","Message");
      return;
  }
      Alert.show("Login Success","Message");
      return;
  }
  private function fReset(event:Event):void
  {
      UserID.text="";
      Pwd.text="";
  }           
]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Image x="246.5" y="10" width="781" height="155" scaleContent="false">
    <mx:source>file:///C|/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/Top.gif</mx:source>
</mx:Image>
<mx:Label x="531" y="262" text="User Name" color="#FFFFFF" fontSize="12" width="84"/>
<mx:Label x="531" y="288" text="Pass Word" color="#FFFFFF" fontSize="12" width="84" height="27"/>
<mx:Label x="531" y="200" text="Login Information" width="297" color="#FFFFFF" fontFamily="Verdana" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="20"/>
<mx:Button x="590" y="323" label="Login" cornerRadius="7" click="clickHandler(event);"/>
<mx:TextInput x="623" y="262" width="160" height="20" id="UserID"/>
<mx:TextInput x="623" y="293" width="160" height="20" id="Pwd"/>
<mx:Button x="688" y="323" label="Reset" cornerRadius="7" click="fReset(event);"/>
</mx:Application>
```

When I run the swf file it runs in small window, but when the user clicks the SWF I want it to open in full screen mode, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Thorough tutorial:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Full Screen Mode, you have to use some javascript.

Adam Kiss' [FlexExamples full-screen example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/) shows you how to do it with Flex's older default javascript file.  I'd recommend using [fullscreen and SWFObject](http://blog.alastairdawson.com/2008/03/01/using-swfobject-to-allow-fullscreen-with-flex-builder/).

You basically have to set the a property on swf object embedded into html to true, using javascript:

`allowFullScreen: true;`

That's it!